# Undefined control sequence. \beamer@doifinframe

Tags: beamer

I'm new with beamer and I'm trying to use the template from the university to make a Master presentation. unfortunately, I encountered some troubles. This is the code!

```
\documentclass[fleqn,15pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetheme[blue,dark,colorblocks,tocinheader,]{tubs}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
\begin{document}
\section{Reliability, Availability, and Maintainability}
\subsection{Reliability}
\begin{frame}{Reliability}
bla bla bla bla 
\begin{center}
\begin{equation}
R\left ( t \right )=\exp ^{(- \lambda .t)}
\end{equation}
\label{eq1}
\end{center}
Where \lamda is the failure rate and can be expressed as:
\begin{center}
\begin{equation}
\lambda = \frac{k}{T}
\end{equation}
\label{eq2}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and I'm getting this error message:
**! Undefined control sequence. \beamer@doifinframe ...\end {center} Where \lamda is the failure rate and ca... l.49 \end{frame}**

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t use the greek symbols outside of math mode and your command is missing a `b`, thus

```
Where \lamda is the failure rate and can be expressed as:
```

should be

```
Where $\lambda$ is the failure rate and can be expressed as:
```

Furthermore you should not use `{center}` around your equations. They are centered by default (you use the `fleqn` document class option, don’t us ist if you don't want flushing equations…) anyway and `{center}` adds extra vertical space.

Appending `\justify` to `\frame` in that way seems to be a bad idea … Just stick do ragged text and take the following advice from beamers manual serious:

> Do not hyphenate words. If absolutely necessary, hyphenate words “by hand”, using the command `\-`.

I prefer having the `\label`s inside of the environment they belong to.

**Full code**

```
\documentclass[15pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usetheme[blue,dark,colorblocks,tocinheader,]{tubs}
%\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Reliability, Availability, and Maintainability}
\subsection{Reliability}
\begin{frame}{Reliability}
bla bla bla bla 
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
   R\left ( t \right )=\exp(- \lambda \cdot t)
\end{equation}
Where $\lambda$ is the failure rate and can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
   \lambda = \frac{k}{T}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*I had to comment the line loading the theme, because it is not part of TeX Live and therefore not installed on my system …*

---

**Edit:**

I just noticed it should be either `\mathrm{e}^{x}` or `\exp(x)` but not `\exp^{x}`. And your `\lambda.t` should probably be `\lambda\cdot t`, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @A.nechi You’re welcome :-)

Comment: @A.nechi: I noticed two more things, please see my edit …

Comment: yes you are right !